# Do I need to load all the css files at the beginning?

Tags: css, sass

I am learning Scss, and reading this article.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/aesthetic-sass-1-architecture-and-style-organization#architecture

Should I load main.scss at beginning, or load the scss file when need it. 
If we should do the second way, then would it be too annoying to import relevant css files every time you create a new page?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Sass compiler to compile the CSS files into CSS. So I suggest using single main.CSS file and import other CSS files into it.

Usually, the compilers compile all the CSS files into their independent CSS files. In order to avoid it name your other CSS files like _scssfile.scss and _scssfile2.scss and import them into the main.scss.

This will create a single CSS file which you can import.

Using a CSS file make a single call on the network, if you use multiple files then the network will call each of them separately.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any practical strategies to load css when it is needed. For example, I will not load page1.css until the page1.html is loaded. Is it too slow to load main.css which contains everything at beginning?

Comment: Well there are many ways to do that.  If your project is a simple one then you can create separate css files and then use them when needed.  There are new technologies (module bundlers ) like webpack and systemjs which does this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include any scss file in your html instead if your file name is (main.scss) you will include (main.css) in your html doc and you need a compiler like http://koala-app.com/ which will auto read the scss and will covert that code in css after you assign the folder to Koala Compiler ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.